# Oracle Apex - A lot of session with nobody user

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a lot of session with nobody user. Any solution how stop this.

Page 9999 is login page, page 2 is default (home page) after login.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Unless I'm wrong, I don't think that there's anything to "stop".

When anyone accesses the login page, session is being created and they are *recorded* as such - **nobody**. Once they log in (providing username and password), `:APP_USER` gets its value which is then equal to username.

When you log out, your session expires, but Apex creates a new - "nobody's" session (that's what Page 2 represents, I believe).

---

Shortly, that's how Apex works, there's nothing you should do about it.

Comment: Tnx for answer, Only on one app I have this situation. This is app rarely use maybe one login per day  other app is use more often.  https://ibb.co/GsX7QMP   I don't understand why it only happens on this one. I don't mind, maybe the only problem is that these logs are entered into the database.